# Selenium Python: how to form a list if some of its elements may not be found

Tags: python, list, selenium

How do you form a list of elements, if some of these elements may not exist. Elements = webpage buttons. Under certain conditions, some of these buttons are not on this page. If so, list is not created, because:

1. Button is not found.
2. List containing such button is not defined.

```py
# This is not working:

try:

    b1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"some xpath1")

    b2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"some xpath2")

    b3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"some xpath3")

except NoSuchElementException:

    print("button not found")

buttons = [b1,b2,b3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Append it from within the try-catch and define the list before the try-catch. Additionally, it will be a TimeoutException, not a NoSuchElementException. Edit your post to have your stack trace on it. Finally, use WebDriverWait, it is better than find_element.

```
# imports you will need for WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

list = []
try:
    list.append(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "some xpath1"))))
    list.append(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "some xpath2"))))
    list.append(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "some xpath3"))))
except TimeoutException:
    print("button not found")
```

This will put the elements in the list. If you are trying to find out the text of each button to make the list more readable you can put .text at the end of each of those WebDriverWaits like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "some xpath1"))).text
```

The last comment on this is that each one of those WebDriverWaits will wait for 10 seconds (the second parameter) before throwing the exception. If you are looking for 3 elements and none are found it will take 30 seconds before it completes. If you don't want to wait that long you can decrease the time but depending on how long your site takes to load it may cause issues if you set it to an extremely low number like 0.1 seconds.